# exposing .Net to COM

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I have some .Net functionality I am trying to use in VB6.  I have followed several tutorials.  I wrote a test program with success using the formula here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM

However, when I try to do it with my actual project, my ProgId doesn't show in the registry like my test file. I made sure property ComVisible == true

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Controls.Graph.Web
{
    [Guid("5F9F6C6F-016A-4CFF-BD7A-3463761807E1")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface _GraphScript
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string getGraphXml();
    }

[Guid("35901BC6-EFF1-490C-84FA-786E8462C553")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId(ProgIds.GraphScript)]
public class GraphScript : _GraphScript
{
    protected GraphScript()     
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The graphs xml and javascript</returns>
    public string getGraphXml()
    {
        DisplayDefaults tempDefaults;
        tempDefaults = new DisplayDefaults();

        GraphConstructor graph = new GraphConstructor();
        graph.constructGraph();
        GraphModel completedGraph = graph.Graph;

        return GraphControl.RenderGraph(completedGraph, tempDefaults, 1) + GraphControl.RenderGraphScript();
    }
}
}
```

and my progid...

```
using System;

namespace Controls.Graph.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ProgID Constant
    /// </summary>
    public static class ProgIds
    {
        public const string GraphScript = "GraphData";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which piece of the puzzle I'm missing here

EDIT: actually the Guid shows up in the registry however the Progid still is not.  Any ideas/suggestions?

also made sure to do this:
[image: registered for com interop]

Comment: How are you registering your assembly? Are you registering it as 32-bit or 64-bit? If you are registering under 32-bit you need to look in the WOW64 registry keys.

Comment: I'm not sure.  How would I find out/specify which one I want?

Comment: OK, it looks like you have `Register for COM interop` taking care of that for you. Do you have your assembly strong-named signed (under the Signing option)? IIRC that's also required for exposing to COM.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means, but I created one. Now what do I do with it?

Comment: Using a protected constructor means "do not allow anybody but me to create an instance".  So you have no use for a progid.  And none will be written.

Comment: @vcsjones: You only need strong name signing when you put your assembly into GAC, otherwise it is not necessary and it is completely unrelated to exposing the assembly to COM http://stackoverflow.com/q/4864892/57428

Comment: @sharptooth fascinating! Today I learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what was wrong.  I needed to change some access modifiers to PUBLIC -- including my `GraphScript()` constructor.